# Use text vertices of Google OCR to print text with its original indentation

Tags: python, indentation, google-vision

Is it possible to convert vertices of Google OCR vision into a text preserving it's original indentation?

For instance using the **example [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22features%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22TEXT_DETECTION%22%7D%5D%2C%22image%22%3A%7B%22source%22%3A%7B%22imageUri%22%3A%22gs%3A%2F%2Fcloud-samples-data%2Fvision%2Focr%2Fsign.jpg%22%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D&hl=fr#vision_set_endpoint-python)**, for the following image

[image]

Google vision returns each detected text with it's 4-vertices (it's Cartesian coordinates).

After executing the **python function** *"detect_text"* we get:

**Result** :

```
"WAITING? PLEASE TURN OFF YOUR ENGINE" bounds: (52,137),(375,137),(375,330),(52,330)

"WAITING" bounds: (59,137),(342,151),(340,190),(57,177)

"?" bounds: (345,151),(375,152),(373,191),(343,190)

"PLEASE" bounds: (204,205),(318,210),(317,232),(203,227)

"TURN" bounds: (205,236),(288,239),(287,261),(204,258)

"OFF" bounds: (301,240),(356,242),(355,263),(300,261)

"YOUR" bounds: (205,269),(290,272),(289,293),(204,290)

"ENGINE" bounds: (205,302),(323,304),(323,326),(205,324)
```

I've found different ways to plot these coordinates, but how can I print the result with it's original indentation?

**Expected output** :

WAITING ?

```
       PLEASE
       TURN OFF
       YOUR
       ENGINE
```

Of course, this will not preserve text formatting, but at least we'll keep relatively original spaces and tabulations!

Thank you in advance!